# Configuring host and port in a CherryPy Python web app with more than one class

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a simple Cherrypy web application, including two classes. The init code looks like this:

```
c = MyClass()
c.updates = AnotherClass()
app = cherrypy.tree.mount(c, '/', 'myapp.config')
c.setConfig(app.config)
c.updates.setConfig(app.config)
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

The setConfig method for both classes is just a line of code to store some database configuration:

```
def setConfig(self, conf):
    self.config = conf['Database']
```

The configuration file myapp.config looks like this:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
server.socket_port = 80

[/]
tools.staticdir.root = com.stuff.myapp.rootDir + '/html'

[Database]
dbtable: "mydbtable"
username: "user"
password: "pass"
```

When I start the lot, the application gets the database config data, and correctly serves static files from the /html directory, but it only listens on localhost on 8080. I get this on the console:

```
[11/Apr/2013:10:03:58] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[11/Apr/2013:10:03:58] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[11/Apr/2013:10:03:58] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[11/Apr/2013:10:03:58] ENGINE Serving on 127.0.0.1:8080
[11/Apr/2013:10:03:58] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

I definitely must have done something wrong. It's as if the global part of the configuration doesn't get applied. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out how to solve it. I added this line:

```
cherrypy.config.update('myapp.config')
```

after the line that says

```
app = cherrypy.tree.mount(c, '/', 'myapp.config')
```

I think the reason why my classes were getting the Database configuration is that I pass it manually with the *setConfig()* calls. This passes the *application* configuration only, not the *global* configuration. The mount() call apparently doesn't propagate the configuration data to the objects it mounts, as I thought it would do.

Furthermore, the *update()* call must be after the *mount()* call, or an exception is raised.

I'm not sure whether this is the best way to organize this code. This works for now, but better ideas are always welcome.